# Cannot install Netbeans 7.3

Tags: installation, 13.04, netbeans

First and first, I had Netbeans installed on my laptop when it was on 12.04 but after I upgraded it to 13.04 and could not find it on my dash so thought it was removed on upgrade.

I tried to reinstall it using the .sh file from they're official website and then I found out that it was already installed so I uninstalled it from my laptop and tried to again to install it(so it would be a fresh install),but when the installer came out it told me that "All components are installed".

After that I tried cleaning my system with ubuntu tweak's janitor and tried again but yet the problem persisted, and after this I manual deleted any directories/files related to netbeans(searched the directories/files with nautilus) and yet the problem is still there.

When the installer start(without errors), it simply says:"All components are installed" and the "Next" button is deactivated.

I installed Netbeans 7.0.1 from software center but I would want to install the latest version.

Any clues/tips/help?

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove netbeans[fullVersionOrSomething]` and then install from your downloaded latest version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Download Netbeans from https://netbeans.org/downloads/
- Make sure you have Java version installed:
  Type this command in a Terminal:

  java -version
  You should get should get an output similar to this:

> java version "1.7.0_21" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_21-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode)

- Next install Netbeans: chmod +x netbeans-7.3-javase-linux.sh;
- Launch installer ./netbeans-7.3-javase-linux.sh
- If you want to install it in /opt launch it with sudo:
  sudo ./netbeans-7.3-javase-linux.sh

See also the instructions: [Installing the Software](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/install.html#installation)

Comment: I don`t understand you! Do you want to install it system wide and for all user or simply for yourself? If so than use the sh file without sudo.

Comment: System wide,but nevermind I will just install it again on the other user.Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me: remove the ~./nbi directory.

1) open terminal

2) rm -r ~/.nbi

Hope it helps.